# SFML 2.3 Window doesn't display anything

Tags: window, render, sfml

I just set up my SFML 2.3 project using the official tutorial from sfml website. Everything runs but the window doesn't display that green circle. The picture below describes the problem clearly. The window just stays like that.

[image]

I used the code from the sfml tutorial on their website. Its the one from Learn -> SFML 2.3 -> SFML with Visual Studio. http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried using SFML 2.1 and it works well. What could it be? My graphics card is an Intel GMA 3150, it does suppot OpenGL up to 1.4. My buid runs on 32bit Windows 7.

Comment: Can we see your code? Looks like your event handling/render loop is not correct.

Comment: I used the code from the sfml tutorial on their website. Its the one from Learn -> SFML 2.3 -> SFML with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFML 2.3 has added support for OpenGL 3. Probably SFML is defaulting to OpenGL 2 or 3. [SFML Changelog 2.3](https://www.sfml-dev.org/changelog.php#sfml-2.3)

Comment: My GPU at that time had no support for OGL 3.0 or upper, so that must be the case. SFML did not fallback to a supported version, so weird things happened. I abandoned working on that machine and bought a newer one.